# Controlar tamanho do resultado curl

Tags: php, libcurl

Ola, tenho que puxar dados de um feed usando Curl em PHP. 
Depois de extraido, eu gravo o resultado no meu banco.

O problema é que o resultado da chamada é gigante. Existe alguma forma de controlar esse fluxo?

Esse é o codigo:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://site.com/?_restfully=true&fromDate=2017-09-07");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer $token";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Acho que você pode usar o `CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION` ou `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`, vou testar aqui e se funcionar eu publico aqui. Se você quiser abortar a conexão se o contéudo for muito grande você tem o `CURLOPT_MAXFILESIZE`, acho que funcionária.

Comment: a função curl_exec retorna qual tipo?

Answer (score 0):

O PHP, *como sempre*, [não tem suporte](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php) para o `CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION` e nem mesmo o `CURLOPT_MAXFILESIZE` está listado ai... Uma forma que vejo, mas não necessariamente a melhor, é usar o `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`, da seguinte maneira:

```
$result = '';
$size = 0;
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://site.com/?_restfully=true&fromDate=2017-09-07");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function($ch, $content) use (&$result, $size){
    $result .= $content;
    $len = strlen($content);
    $size += $len;

    if($size > 1000){
        return 0;
    }

    return $len;
});
curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) !== 200) {
    die();
}

echo $result;
```

Dessa forma o resultado será limitado até 1000 bytes. Na verdade esse limite não é tão rígido, o `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` não há chamado a cada byte recebido, mas sim a cada "bloco" de dado, ou seja pode ser que haja 1000 bytes ou 500 bytes. Por esse motivo pode ser que o `result` tenha mais do que 1000 bytes, porém quando existem mais de 1000 bytes ele vai parar de obter o resto.